# document.getElementById("id").style.display = 'hidden'; not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner in JavaScript and web dev in general, and I am writing a simple web program to get a random number between 1-99, then take guesses from the user. The problem is that I want to display images based on the users guess either too low, too high, or correct. As far as I can tell, I have all the code required to initially hide the images, then reveal them when a condition is met. For some reason none of my document.getElementById("id").style.display = 'block'; or
document.getElementById("id").style.display = 'none'; seem to work.
Any help is appreciated.

```js
function hideTooHigh() {
    document.getElementById("tooHigh").style.display = 'hidden';
}

function hideTooLow() {
    document.getElementById("tooLow").style.display = 'hidden';
}

function hideCorrect() {
    document.getElementById("correct").style.display = 'hidden';
}

function guessinggame() {
    var answer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var input = 0;

    while (input != answer) {
        hideTooHigh();
        hideTooLow();
        hideCorrect();
        var inputstring = prompt("Please enter your guess", "0");
        var input = parseInt(inputstring);
        if (input < answer) {
            // display less than image
            document.getElementById("tooLow").style.display = 'block';

            // setTimeout(hideTooLow, 3000);
        } else if (input > answer) {
            // display greater than image
            document.getElementById("tooHigh").style.display = 'block';
            // setTimeout(hideTooHigh, 3000);
        }

    }
    if (input == answer) {
        // display correct image
        document.getElementById("correct").style.display = 'block';
        // setTimeout(hideCorrect, 3000);
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

    <title>Number Guessing Game</title>
    <script src="guessinggame.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Click button to begin the guessing game</h1>
    <p>To play, guess a whole number between 1-99 by typing it into the prompt window and pressing enter.<br>Depending on if you are too high, too low, or correct on your guess one of the images will display below. Too high displays a down arrow, while too
        low displays an up arrow.</p>
    <button onclick="guessinggame()">Play!</button>
    <div id="tooHigh"><img src="toohigh.jpg" width="250" height="250"></div>
    <div id="tooLow"><img src="toolow.png" width="250" height="250"></div>
    <div id="correct"><img src="correct.jpg" width="250" height="250"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're asking for debugging help, but you haven't reduced your program to something that illustrates the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

1. You can't structure your JavaScript code that way. JavaScript code runs in an event loop. On browsers, your main JavaScript code (the code in your `script` elements) is executed by the same thread that updates the page display. So when your code gets called, it needs to do its work and then return so the browser can update whatever you've changed. Instead of `prompt` in a `while` loop, use an `input` element on the page and a button the user clicks to submit their guess. A click handler on the button would have the code that's currently in the body of your `while` loop.
2. The `display` property's value for "don't show" is `none`. (`hidden` is for the `visibility` property.)

   So

   ```
   document.getElementById("tooHigh").style.display = 'hidden';
   ```

   should be

   ```
   document.getElementById("tooHigh").style.display = 'none';
   // -------------------------------------------------^^^^
   ```

Comment: The `prompt` in the `while` loop is also blocking, preventing rendering

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Heh, hadn't got that far, was looking for a dupetarget for the `display` property. :-) If you want to post an answer covering both, I can delete this.

Comment: @Kryptur - Doh! Had it right in the code example, wrong in the opening sentence. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much @T.J.Crowder, this is my first JavaScript app so I wasn't sure about the single thread concept until you told me and I researched it. I did what you suggested and the app now works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an answer only related to display through javascript then use visibility instead of display.

1. `document.getElementById("tooHigh").style.visibility = 'hidden'`; for hiding the content
2. `document.getElementById("tooHigh").style.visibility = 'visible'`; for showing the content

Answer (score 0):

you use 'hidden' not 'none'

document.getElementById("tooLow").style.display = 'hidden';

try this:

document.getElementById("tooLow").style.display = 'none';